# R: removing half of the confidence bands

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, plotly, data-visualization

I am using the R programming language. I create the following data and graph:

```
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

#time series 1
date_decision_made = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")

property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,100,10)

final_data <- data.frame(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars)


#####aggregate

final_data$year_month <- format(as.Date(final_data$date_decision_made), "%Y-%m")
final_data$year_month <- as.factor(final_data$year_month)


f = final_data %>% group_by (year_month) %>% summarise(max_value = max(property_damages_in_dollars), mean_value = mean(property_damages_in_dollars), min_value = min(property_damages_in_dollars))



####plot####

fig <- plot_ly(f, x = ~year_month, y = ~max_value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
        line = list(color = 'transparent'),
        showlegend = FALSE, name = 'max_value') 

fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~min_value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
            fill = 'tonexty', fillcolor='rgba(0,100,80,0.2)', line = list(color = 'transparent'),
            showlegend = FALSE, name = 'min_value') 

fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~year_month, y = ~mean_value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
            line = list(color='rgb(0,100,80)'),
            name = 'Average') 


fig <- fig %>% layout(title = "Average Property Damages",
         paper_bgcolor='rgb(255,255,255)', plot_bgcolor='rgb(229,229,229)',
         xaxis = list(title = "Months",
                      gridcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                      showgrid = TRUE,
                      showline = FALSE,
                      showticklabels = TRUE,
                      tickcolor = 'rgb(127,127,127)',
                      ticks = 'outside',
                      zeroline = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(title = "Dollars",
                      gridcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                      showgrid = TRUE,
                      showline = FALSE,
                      showticklabels = TRUE,
                      tickcolor = 'rgb(127,127,127)',
                      ticks = 'outside',
                      zeroline = FALSE))

fig
```

[image]

I tried removing the bottom half as follows :

```
fig <- plot_ly(f, x = ~year_month, y = ~max_value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
        line = list(color = 'transparent'),
        showlegend = FALSE, name = 'max_value') 


fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~year_month, y = ~mean_value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
            line = list(color='rgb(0,100,80)'),
            name = 'Average') 


fig <- fig %>% layout(title = "Average Property Damages",
         paper_bgcolor='rgb(255,255,255)', plot_bgcolor='rgb(229,229,229)',
         xaxis = list(title = "Months",
                      gridcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                      showgrid = TRUE,
                      showline = FALSE,
                      showticklabels = TRUE,
                      tickcolor = 'rgb(127,127,127)',
                      ticks = 'outside',
                      zeroline = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(title = "Dollars",
                      gridcolor = 'rgb(255,255,255)',
                      showgrid = TRUE,
                      showline = FALSE,
                      showticklabels = TRUE,
                      tickcolor = 'rgb(127,127,127)',
                      ticks = 'outside',
                      zeroline = FALSE))
```

I am trying to remove the bottom part of this graph:

But this takes off both the top and the bottom:

[image]

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong? How do I remove the bottom band and only keep the top ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plotting function you are using from plotly is shading everything between `min_value` and `max_value`. You want it to shade everything between `mean_value` and `max_value`. Hence try replacing `min_value` with `mean_value`.

```r
# unchanged
fig <- plot_ly(f, x = ~year_month, y = ~max_value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
        line = list(color = 'transparent'),
        showlegend = FALSE, name = 'max_value') 

# the replacement happens here
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~mean_value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
            fill = 'tonexty', fillcolor='rgba(0,100,80,0.2)', line = list(color = 'transparent'),
            showlegend = FALSE, name = 'min_value') 

# unchanged
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~year_month, y = ~mean_value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
            line = list(color='rgb(0,100,80)'),
            name = 'Average')
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! it's so elegant and simple - replacing "min" with "mean". I wish i had thought about that! thanks again - everything works perfectly!