# R: changing the color of lines in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, plotly, data-visualization

I am using R. I am trying to change the color of different lines on a graph. I figured out how to make each line a different color in the code below:

```
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)

#time series 1
date_decision_made = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")

property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,100,10)

final_data <- data.frame(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars)

final_data %>%
  mutate(date_decision_made = as.Date(date_decision_made)) %>%
  add_count(week = format(date_decision_made, "%W-%y"))

final_data$class = "time_series_1"


#time series 2
date_decision_made = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")

date_decision_made <- format(as.Date(date_decision_made), "%Y/%m/%d")

property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,10,10)

final_data_2 <- data.frame(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars)

final_data_2 %>%
  mutate(date_decision_made = as.Date(date_decision_made)) %>%
  add_count(week = format(date_decision_made, "%W-%y"))

final_data_2$class = "time_series_2"


#time series 3
date_decision_made = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")

date_decision_made <- format(as.Date(date_decision_made), "%Y/%m/%d")

property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,50,50)

final_data_3<- data.frame(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars)

final_data_3 %>%
  mutate(date_decision_made = as.Date(date_decision_made)) %>%
  add_count(week = format(date_decision_made, "%W-%y"))

final_data_3$class = "time_series_3"



#time series 4
date_decision_made = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"),by="day")

date_decision_made <- format(as.Date(date_decision_made), "%Y/%m/%d")

property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,50,50)

final_data_4<- data.frame(date_decision_made, property_damages_in_dollars)

final_data_4 %>%
  mutate(date_decision_made = as.Date(date_decision_made)) %>%
  add_count(week = format(date_decision_made, "%W-%y"))

final_data_4$class = "time_series_4"

data = rbind(final_data, final_data_2, final_data_3, final_data_4)

a = data  %>% 
    
    group_by(class) %>% 
    plot_ly(x = ~ (date_decision_made)) %>% 
    add_lines(y = ~ property_damages_in_dollars, 
              color = ~ factor(class)
    )
```

[image]

Is there a way to make (time series 1 , time series 2) the same color and (time series 3, time series 4) the same color?

I tried the following code, but now there are only 2 time series instead of 4:

```
final_data_4$class = "red"
final_data_3$class = "red"
final_data_2$class = "blue"
final_data$class = "blue"

data = rbind(final_data, final_data_2, final_data_3, final_data_4)

a = data  %>% 
    
    group_by(class) %>% 
    plot_ly(x = ~ (date_decision_made)) %>% 
    add_lines(y = ~ property_damages_in_dollars, 
              color = ~ factor(class)
    )
```

[image]

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong? I want there to be 4 time series, the first two to be one color and the other two be the same color.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(xts)

dat <- matrix(rnorm(400), ncol = 4)
tindex <- seq.Date(from = Sys.Date()-99,
                   to = Sys.Date(),
                   by = 'days')

dat_xts <- xts(dat, order.by = tindex)
names(dat_xts) <- paste0('ts', 1:4)

plot.xts(dat_xts, col = c('red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'),
         legend.loc = 'bottomright')
```

[image]

Using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

autoplot(dat_xts, facets = FALSE) + scale_color_manual(values= c('red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Can this be converted into a plotly object? With the ggplotly() function? Thanks you for all your help!

Comment: Thank you! I will see if autoplot is compatible with ggplotly.

Comment: Can you please take a look at these questions if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65655864/r-plotting-multiple-confidence-intervals-on-the-same-graph , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657858/r-removing-half-of-the-confidence-bands

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65650991/r-overlaying-points-on-a-graph